# What is the entropy of an image and how is it calculated?

Tags: image-processing, statistics, entropy

I have learnt that it is the randomness of the pixels. But please help with how this randomness is being calculated mathematically. And also how different images will have different entropy.

Comment: It's not really the randomness, rather how unexpected each value is given the other values. Thus, it is related to the amount of information present in the image.

Answer (score 23):

You may as well calculate the Shannon entropy straight from your `img`. Just do:

```
import skimage.measure    
entropy = skimage.measure.shannon_entropy(img)
```

If you want to see the maths behind:

```
import numpy as np
marg = np.histogramdd(np.ravel(img), bins = 256)[0]/img.size
marg = list(filter(lambda p: p > 0, np.ravel(marg)))
entropy = -np.sum(np.multiply(marg, np.log2(marg)))
```

First, `marg` is the marginal distribution of the two dimensional grayscale image `img`. `bins` is set to 256 for an 8-bit image. Then you need to filter out the probabilities that are equal to zero and finally sum over the remaining elements `np.multiply(marg, np.log2(marg))`, as defined by [Shannon's entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)).

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'skimage' has no attribute 'measure'
`

Comment: @mLstudent33 `import skimage.measure`

Comment: Thx for showing the math behind shannon_entropy() function.  How many bins does skimage.measure.shannon_entropy() use if the pixels of the grayscale image are of type 32 bit float?

Answer (score 5):

The entropy of an image is defined as follows:

[image: entropy]

where *n* is the number of gray levels (256 for 8-bit images), *p*<sub>*i*</sub> is the probability of a pixel having gray level *i*, and *b* is the base of the logarithm function.

Notice that the entropy of an image is rather different from the entropy feature extracted from the GLCM (Gray-Level Co-occurrence Matrix) of an image. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40919936/calculating-entropy-from-glcm-of-an-image) to learn more.

As per your request, I'm attaching an example of how the entropy of a GLCM is computed:

First we import the necessary modules:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.feature import greycomatrix
```

Then we read the image:

```
img = io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/07DZW.png')
```

[image: lion]

The GLCM (corresponding to *the pixel to the right*) of the image above is computed as follows:

```
glcm = np.squeeze(greycomatrix(img, distances=[1], 
                               angles=[0], symmetric=True, 
                               normed=True))
```

And finally we apply this formula to calculate the entropy:

[image: entropy]

where *p(i, j)* represents the entries of the GLCM.

If we set *b* to 2, the result is expressed in **bits**.

```
entropy = -np.sum(glcm*np.log2(glcm + (glcm==0)))
# yields 10.704625483788325
```

Comment: What does "corresponding to the pixel to the right" mean?  Off of the image?

Comment: The GLCM models the distribution of co-occurring pixel values at a given offset. In the example above the _offset_ used to compute the GLCM is "one pixel to the right".

Comment: @Tonechas if i want to calculate the entropy for a color picture what should i do? .. this code is working only for grayscale.

Comment: Replacing pᵢ, the probability of gray level `i`,  by the joint probability of color `(r, g, b)`, pʳᵍᵇ, would do the trick. Yo need to introduce this change into the first formula.

Comment: Note your edit requests. The equations look terrible to the point of unreadability.